# Using ExecutorService in a service in android

Tags: android, service, executorservice

In my application, I am using ExecutorService from an activity.
I want to convert that activity to a service running in background.

I have all changes made, but the "submit" of the ExecutorService gives me a problem.

In my activity:

```
ExecutorService private mExecutor;

...

mExecutor.submit (new MY_ACTIVITY.LoadScaledImageTask (getApplicationContext (), outputUri, calcImageSize ()));
```

How can declare the same "submit" in the service, 
not extending activity?

I tried it with "getApplicationContext" and many other possibilities, but without success

How would the right way?

Thank you very much and greetings

Comment: What is the type of the parameter? `Context`?

Comment: What is the problem? It is not clear. What is the obstacle for using _"submit in the service, not extending activity"_? Can't `LoadScaledImageTask` class be declared within the service?

Comment: You're right, I was confused with some concepts ... Too many hours in front of the same code :) Thanks!